# Assigning Param by Iterating Through Enum

Tags: java, for-loop, enums, iteration, bag

I'm attempting to create and add some Card objects to a bag. The Card objects have enum values for their suits and ranks and I'm really trying to avoid having to create 52 unique object - one at a time. I'd like to assign the ranks by iterating through the Rank enum (Suits is also an enum) of the class like so:

```
for (Card.Ranks r: Card.Ranks.values())
{
    theShoe.addItem(new Card(Card.Suits.Diamonds, Card.r.values()));
    theShoe.addItem(new Card(Card.Suits.Hearts, Card.r.values()));
    theShoe.addItem(new Card(Card.Suits.Spades, Card.r.values()));
    theShoe.addItem(new Card(Card.Suits.Clubs, Card.r.values()));
}
```

The Card constructor looks like:

```
public Card(Suits s, Ranks r)
{
    suit = s;
    rank = r;
}
```

But it's definitely not working. Eclipse is asking me to create a field or constant "r" in the Card class. :/ Is there another way for me to do this?
I've tried removing the ".values()" at the end of each line but that doesn't work either. Would really appreciate if someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong and if I can fix it somehow. Thanks!

Comment: What does the `Card` constructor take? Also, is `Suits` another `enum`?

Comment: Please upload source code of the `Card` class. Also, if you could upload the error you are seeing that would help too.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch updated in the question and Yes both Suits and Ranks are enums

Comment: @JonathanThoms made according edits in the question

Comment: It's not working, because when you do:
for (Card.Ranks r : Cards.Ranks.values()) {

The r already is a Ranks enum, so, instead of using  
theShoe.addItem(new Card(Card.Suits.Diamonds, Card.r.values()));
Try: 
 theShoe.addItem(new Card(Card.Suits.Diamonds, r));

And if you want to iterate also through the Suits, do a nested for

Comment: @JoãoAntunes thanks so much! @ElliottFrisch suggested the nested for loop but I had just asked him if I could have written `theShoe.addItem(new Card(Card.Suits.Diamonds, Card.r));` as well - haha, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your constructor, pass a `Suit` and a `Rank`. Something like,

```
for (Card.Ranks r : Card.Ranks.values()) {
    for (Card.Suit s : Card.Suit.values()) { // <-- also loop over the Suits
        theShoe.addItem(new Card(s, r));
    }
}
```

**or**

```
for (Card.Suit s : Card.Suit.values()) { 
    for (Card.Ranks r : Card.Ranks.values()) {
        theShoe.addItem(new Card(s, r));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much! Final question: could I have done this: `theShoe.addItem(new Card(Card.Suits.Diamonds, r));` instead (obviously less efficient but for understanding purposes)?

Comment: @Her Yes. Without the loop over `Card.Suit.values()` (and you'd need the other three `Suits` as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can call the values() method on your enum.

```
for ((Card.Ranks r : Card.Ranks.values()) {
  // do what you want
}
```

This values() method ***is implicitly declared by the compiler***. So it is not listed on Enum doc.